# Why do I get ssh connection error after installing MYSQL server on Ubuntu 18.04 running on AWS (Lightsail and EC2)?

Tags: mysql, amazon-ec2, ubuntu-18.04, amazon-lightsail

So I followed this [tutorial](https://support.rackspace.com/how-to/install-mysql-server-on-the-ubuntu-operating-system/) to install and configure a MySQL server on an AWS instance that was originally running on EC2.
When I tried to login back to the server via ssh, I would get a `port 22: Connection timed out` error.

So I tried to do the same on Lightsail and ended up getting the same error when I try to login back.

Is this a known issue? Am I doing anything wrong? Is there a way to fix this?

Thanks.

Comment: sorry, is not clear to me. Do you mean that you have an existing EC2 on which you were able to login on port 22 and launch commands from the command line ? Then after installing and running MySql and rebooting you cannot login anymore ?

Comment: Yes. Exactly that.

Comment: I am not finding any relationship between a MySql installation and SSH. My first guess is that perhaps you have assigned a public IP to the EC2 instance and not to the network interface. In this case when you reboot the machine you get a new IP but you are trying to connect to the old IP that is not existing anymore. Just a guess, but have a look at the instance dashboard in the console to see if your IP has changed.

Comment: I assigned a static IP to the Lightsail instance. It still won't connect.

Answer (score 0):

mentioned tutorial says:  enable firewall to allow mysql remote access.

```
sudo ufw enable
sudo ufw allow mysql
```

which is allowing only mysql  and stopping every incoming request it can be either ssh or http or anything else which you have defied in security group of ec2 instance.

In my case i have allowed following inbound rule but nothing was working even ssh also says connection refused[image]

To get this working either disable firewall or allow required port in firewall. Off course, still you need to login into ec2 instance to get this done.
There are 3 ways to connect with ec2 instance

[image]

SSH is not working so I choose Session Manager (Browser based ssh). I follow this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uE0jGmZ2PRc) and was able to connect with instance through session manager.

After login i just disable the firewall and every thing works fine.

`sudo ufw disable`

All the inbound rules working properly. Hope it will work for you.